# obtain global maximum of a fitted smoothing spline from R function 'smooth.spline'

Tags: r, spline, smoothing

I smoothed my data using `smooth.spline(x,y)` and now I want to calculate the mode or maximum of smoothed curve.

```
x <- vect.1
y <- vect.2
plot(x, y, type = 'l')
smth <- smooth.spline(x, y)
lines(smth, col = 'red', lwd = 2)
```

[image: data graph along with its smoothed curve]

My current approach is simply to look up the `x` which gives me the maximum `y` which is not so accurate. Is there a better way for doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
psmth <- predict(smth, x= seq(1,100, by=0.1) )
mode_psmth <- psmth$y[ which.max( psmth$y ) ]
```

Or even:

```
mode_psmth <- max(psmth$y)
```

If this is not "sufficiently accurate", then please explain why.

Comment: thanks i think it should be psmth$'x'[which.max(psmth$'y')] to work, you may know supervisors are hard to be convinced, they want computer to tell the  number not the eye!

Comment: Right ... It probably should be something different but I think `psmth$y` would be the mode. And mow that I think about it wouldn't it be easier to just use `max(psmth$y)`?I test my code when a reproducible test case is offered.